# Flappy Bird floor bugging

Tags: javascript, css, flappy-bird-clone

I've been starting to code with html/css/js.

```
.ground-moving {           
    height: 150px;
    width: 580px;
    left: 80px;
    position:  absolute;
    background-image: url('bottom-background.png');
    animation: slideright 100s infinite linear;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: +1;
}
```

i want the floor to move from the right side to left side. But now my floor is on the top of the screen and is super fast.

Can someone help? Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh5wn.png)

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Comment: "*but now"* - so what have you changed since it wasn't like this?  Looks like `z-index` and `animation: 100s`.